# Await Task 'getting lost' with dbContext.savechanges()

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, task-parallel-library

I've had an issue a bit like this occasionally with Task.Run()/Task.Factory.StartNew(), so I think there must be something very basic I'm not understanding about its use (for those who like curly braces, my apologies for having to muddle through VB):

I have an async method with the following code:

```
       Try
        Using context As New ECOSSContext


            context.Meters.Attach(entity)


            Await Task.Run(Sub() _
                               context.SaveChanges() _
                               )

            'ANY CODE HERE NEVER GETS FIRED


        End Using

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
```

It is called from a synchronous method like so:

```
Dim result = ModelService.MeterResolution.SaveMeter(data).Result
```

From what I *understood* this should wait until the method SaveMeter() returns with a result. And the async method I laid out previously should wait on the Task.Run line until it returns, and then continues (hence the await). Instead, what happens is that as soon as the Await line is hit, the callstack seems to exit. The SaveChanges() succeeds, but I'm unable to inform the client of this fact.

I use the TPL relatively frequently in a different application and haven't had these issues, but there's no method like context.SaveChanges() I need to use.

Any suggestions are appreciated. I hope i'm not just mis-reading the documentation.

Comment: Unless this is one of the EF6 releases, its generally not a good idea to use a `DbContext` on multiple threads.  What you probably want to do is move that entire function into an asynchronous method, make sure your `DbContext` is created, used, and destroyed on a single thread.

Comment: @CodingGorilla -- thanks for the tip. What is the reason/authority for this particular guidline?

Comment: See this FAQ: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3739.entity-framework-faq-objectcontext.aspx#What_is_the_recommendation_for_running_a_multithreaded_application_on_the_Entity_Framework_Is_the_Entity_Framework_thread-safe

Comment: @CodingGorilla -- thanks. This doesn't apply since I'm in a highly distributed system and thus I open and close a context for each operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is actually due to your use of `Result`. Calling `async` code from synchronous code can be quite tricky.

I explain the [full reasons for this deadlock on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). In short, there's a "context" that is saved by default at the beginning of each `await` and used to resume the method.

So if this is called in a UI or ASP.NET context, when the `await` completes, the `async` method tries to re-enter that context to continue executing. Unfortunately, code using `Result` (or `Wait`) will block a thread in that context, so the `async` method cannot complete.

The guidelines to avoid this are:

1. Use `ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)` as much as possible. This enables your `async` methods to continue executing without having to re-enter the context.
2. Use `async` all the way. Use `await` instead of `Result` or `Wait`.

Comment: Interesting -- I'll dig into your blog a bit and get back to you.

Comment: That's a really well-written blog you have there. Thanks for the help -- and I apologize for asking a question that comes up so much!